# find nesting depth

Tags: php, jquery

So, take this html for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to find out the maximum depth of this structure, in this example it would be 3, as the structure goes 3 levels down. But the structure can have an arbitrary depth.

Either a javascript/jquery solution or a PHP based solution using the DOM extension would be fine. I really cant think of any nice way of doing this. Maybe there is an xpath expression that does exactly what I want?

EDIT: To clarify: Depth in this case is the maximum nesting of `ul` elements, in this case 3.

Comment: How do you define *depth*? IMO the max. depth in the given example is at least 8, because there's "ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>a>text" in the 6th-last line.

Comment: @M4N Ah, you are right, but in this case I only count the ul´s as a "level", so its 3 as the "deepest" ul is basically selectable as ul ul ul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't want to have to specify the lowest selector, this will give you the maximum number of nest levels:

```
var n = 0

$('ul').each(function(i){ 
    if (($(this).parents('ul').length + 1) > n) { n = $(this).parents('ul').length + 1; }
});
```

Edit: the variable n contains the number of nest levels, so for the example above, 3.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you already accepted an answer, I'm going to throw this one out there since I think it will be more efficient.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/3haSq/

```
Math.max.apply(null, $('ul:not(:has(ul))').map(function() {
    return $(this).parents('ul').length;
}).get()) + 1;
```

- `$('ul:not(:has(ul))')` only concerns itself with `<ul>` elements that do *not* have a nested `<ul>`
- `.map().get()` gives you an array of the quantities of their parent `<ul>` elements
- The native `Math.max()` finds the maximum
- Add `+1` at the end to represent the `<ul>` that was originally selected.

---

**EDIT:**

The reason we're doing `Math.max.apply()` instead of `Math.max()` is pretty simple.

Normally `Math.max()` requires several `int` arguments, like this:

```
Math.max(12, 23, 34);  // results in `34`
```

This is fine as long as you know exactly how many arguments there will be beforehand. Not the situation here.

Normally the `.apply()` method is used to call a function but change the value `this` for that function call. The *first* parameter for `.apply()` is the new value of `this`. Here we're passing `null` because we really don't care what the value is.

The important part of `.apply()` that we care about is the second parameter that takes an `Array` of arguments that would normally be passed to the function. So taking the example above, we would do this:

```
Math.max.apply(null, [12,23,34]);  // Converts the Array to a list of arguments
```

So as you can see, this allows `Math.max()` to accept one Array of `int`s instead of several comma separated `int`s.

*(There is a similar method called `.call()` which takes parameters in the same manner as the original function. As in:)*

```
Math.max.call(null, 12,23,34);   // This version takes several arguments
                                 //     instead of one Array.
```

Comment: @Max - You're welcome, and thanks. :o) Let me know if it needs further explanation.

Comment: Well, one question: what exactly does Math.max.apply() do? Why doesn´t it work e. g. with just Math.max()?

Comment: @Max - Good question. I'll update my answer in a minute to give an explanation.

Comment: @Max - Updated my answer. So because we've reduced the number of `<ul>` elements, and because we're using a native `Math` method instead of comparison operators with variable updates, you'll get better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Pretty neat trick, really. I´d give you another upvote if I could, thank you very much!

Comment: @Max - Not a problem. Glad I could help. :o)

Answer (score 1):

The "nice" way would be to count the parents of a specific element. Lets say, there was an anchor with the id == `foobar`, you could do

```
$('#foobar').parents.length - 1
```

that would return the number of parent nodes, which also would be the depth.

And the "ugly" way would be a recursive function which crawls through every element in your markup until there are no more `child nodes`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no ids available. Furthermore this would count ALL parent nodes of #foobar, not just the parent uls of the node?

Comment: @Max: You could pass `parents()` a selector string. So if you're only interested in `uls` it would be `$('#foobar').parents('ul').length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

This recursive function would work, if you wanted to specify the root. I've used "body" in the following example:

```
function Recurse($item, depth) {
    $item.each(function() {
        depth.count++;
        if (depth.count > depth.max) {
            depth.max = depth.count;
        }
        Recurse($(this).children(), depth);
    });
    depth.count--;
    return depth.max;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(Recurse($("body"), { count: 0, max:0 }));
}
```

Also here at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RqHzf/

Comment: Awesome function btw, for another project I could translate this easily to PHP - counting the levels of an array structure!